# How to user a condition in a String inside an IF sentence

Tags: javascript, string, boolean, eval, conditional-statements

I have the following situation:

```
var answer = 'three';
var isClosed = true;
var condition = "answer != null && !isClosed";
```

The condition is a literal string and it's dynamically set by the user. Once they set the condition, I need to evaluate it inside an IF/ELSE sentence:

```
if(condition)
   //Do something
else
   //Do something
```

Can I do that without using "eval()"? How? I want to avoid it:

```
if(eval(condition))
...
```

NOTE: This is a simple example, the real situation is a bit complex with dynamic conditions :)

Comment: Why not just do "var condition = answer != null && !isClosed;"  ?

Comment: @Mironor Not exactly, the conditions are loaded as a string on a database by technician users. The conditions may depend on different variables that are defined on another table and frequently updated.

Comment: Couldn't you have a function that goes from the different variables to the condition you want?

Comment: So answer and isClosed cannot be extracted individually?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evade `eval` at all cost (as it can be really dangerous for the security reasons), you basically need a `rules engine` adapted to your `dsl` that you get from the database.

I googled this one and it seems prety decent [C2FO](https://github.com/C2FO/nools) , didn't actually tried it, but now you know where to start.

Comment: So, is that engine adaptable to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

A bit confused.. 
But if the `answer` and `isClosed` set by the user.. then just something like this will suffice..

```
answer = null
isClosed = false // the default value for isClosed
if(answer != null && !isClosed){
  //Do something
}
else{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: I wish I could, but it's more complex than the example and I cannot change this crazy requirement...

Comment: hmm, in that case you already got the answer, 'eval()' is the way to go.. but still not the best way to go as 'eval()' just adds to the runtime complexity of the function